# Creating a node cross-referencing another domain in Sphinx

Tags: python-sphinx, docutils

Within a custom Sphinx domain, I'd like to create a reference to another node in a different domain. For example:

```
.. py:class:: foo.bar

   Lorem ipsum.

.. example:directive:: baz -> foo.bar

   Sit amet, sit.
```

My `example:directive::` says that my "method" `baz` returns something of type `foo.bar`, which is a Python class. So I'd like to cross-reference that to the other `py:class:: foo.bar` description.

```py
from sphinx.directives import ObjectDescription

class ExampleDescription(ObjectDescription):
    def handle_signature(self, sig, signode):

        # lots of parsing and node creation here

        # parsed_annotation = "foo.bar"
        signode += addnodes.desc_returns(parsed_annotation, parsed_annotation)
```

Within my custom domain I'm parsing my directives and building the elements and it's all fine, even cross-referencing within my `example` domain works just fine by subclassing the `sphinx.domains.Domain:resolve_xref` method. I'm just unsure how I would programmatically insert a node in my `handle_signature` method which is later resolved to a node in another domain. Would I somehow have to instantiate a `sphinx.domains.python.PyXRefRole`?

The expected result in HTML would be something like:

```
<dl>
  <dt>
    <code>baz</code>
    →
    <a href="example.html#py.class.foo.bar">
      <code>foo.bar</code>
    </a>
  </dt>
</dl>
```

Comment: The "docutils" tag is a bit misleading, as the concept of *domains* is unknown in "pure" Docutils. How about changing it to "restructuredtext"?